# Как вывести из бд ограниченное количество записей (RedBean)

Tags: redbeanphp

Ситуация такая, идёт условие, пока в таблице(html) нет 5 записей, туда вносятся данные из бд, после условие повторяется для следующей таблицы(html) и т.д. И вот я не могу понять, как это реализовать используя ORM Redbean PHP.

Вывел всю таблицу а дальше, стопор...

```
$z = "SELECT * FROM `gnet` order by rand()";
$bd = R::getall($z);
foreach ($bd as &$item) :
$nickname = "<td><span>" . $item['nickname'] . "</span></td>";
$fio = "<td width='140px'><span>" . $item['fio'] . "</span></td>";
$mmr = "<td width='140px'><span>" . $item['mmr'] . "</span></td>";
$gcoin = "<td><span>" . $item['gcoin'] . "</span></td>";
$lose = "<td><span>" . $item['lose'] . "</span></td>";
$win = "<td><span>" . $item['win'] . "</span></td>";
echo "<tr>" . $nickname . $fio . $mmr . $status . $gcoin . $lose . $win . "</tr>";
endforeach;
```

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста, код - что попробовали?

Comment: Я вывел всю таблицу, а после пытался искать в инете как это провернуть, нашёл, что можно через условие `while($row=mysql_fetch_array($array))`, но я же использую RedBean, а значит не могу это сделать...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я сделал так и всё вроде как правильно:

```
<?php
require 'libs/db.php'; 
$game = R::getall("SELECT*FROM `gusers` WHERE `lose`='0' AND `WIN`='0'");
shuffle($game);
$i=5;
$team = '1';
while (!empty($game))
{
    echo '<table border=1>

    <thead>                     
   <tr>
    <th scope="col">Ник</th>
    <th scope="col">ММР</th>
    <th scope="col">L</th>
    <th scope="col">W</th>
   </tr>
</thead>
Команда '.$team.'
<tbody >';
    // echo 'Команда - ',$team.'<br>';
foreach ($game as $key=>$gamers) {
    if ($key<$i)
    {
    echo "<tr><td><span>".$gamers['nickname']."</span></td>";
    echo "<td><span>".$gamers['mmr']."</span></td>";
    echo "<td><span>".$gamers['lose']."</span></td>";
    echo "<td><span>".$gamers['win']."</span></td></tr>";
    unset($game[$key]);
    }
}

echo "</tbody></table>";
$i=$i+5;
$team += 1;
echo "<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

А зачем Вам велосипед с getAll? Используйте лучше find или findAll

Попробуйте так:

```
$bd = R::findAll('gnet', 'ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 5');
foreach ($bd as &$item) :
$nickname = "<td><span>" . $item['nickname'] . "</span></td>";
$fio = "<td width='140px'><span>" . $item['fio'] . "</span></td>";
$mmr = "<td width='140px'><span>" . $item['mmr'] . "</span></td>";
$gcoin = "<td><span>" . $item['gcoin'] . "</span></td>";
$lose = "<td><span>" . $item['lose'] . "</span></td>";
$win = "<td><span>" . $item['win'] . "</span></td>";
echo "<tr>" . $nickname . $fio . $mmr . $status . $gcoin . $lose . $win . "</tr>";
endforeach;
```

Comment: Спасибо, но разве он не выведет одинаковые записи?

Comment: В данном запросе он возьмёт 5 записей из таблица 'gnet' в том порядке, в котором Вы зададите параметром ORDER BY.

Comment: Да но прикол в том, что он возьмет лишь 5, а мне надо чтобы было лимит таблицы html 5 штук и потом если еще есть то еще одна таблица и т.д и всё заполняется(читайте выше!)